# How to change default max. cpc to auto using google adword API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, google-ads-api

I need to change google ad group 'default max.cpc' field to auto. Currently it is picking adgroup budget and stores it as default max. cpc value which I don't want.

I am using PHP lib for google Adword API calls provided by google.

Below is the screen shot.

http://prntscr.com/jrtpj1

Please any one help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `BiddingScheme` for AdGroup to [EnhancedCpcBiddingScheme](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201802/AdGroupCriterionService.EnhancedCpcBiddingScheme)

What is `EnhancedCpcBiddingScheme`?

Enhanced CPC is a bidding strategy that raises your bids for clicks that seem more likely to lead to a conversion and lowers them for clicks where they seem less likely. This bidding scheme does not support criteria level bidding strategy overrides.

Above scheme will change cpc in auto mode.